# Boolean not shown in edit mode (Solved)

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

[image]
The anvil in edit mode (I put a mirror modifier on the x axis) and the boolean doesn't work on the anvil.

[image]
The anvil in object mode and the boolean works on the anvil.

[3]: [image]

Comment: that's the way it works, if you want to see the mesh modified you need to apply the modifier

Comment: oh, how come i didn't notice that? Thank you.